# RankedMax and Max do not behave identically

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have spent three hours debugging some code and at the end I think I found a bug. Otherwise I cannot explain what I am seeing:

When I want to use `RankedMax` on nested sublists, Mathematica freaks out, but it works all smooth as I expect when I use `Max`.

Try:

```
tab = Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 4}] // TableForm
Map[Function[{x}, x/Max[x]], tab] // TableForm
Map[Function[{x}, x/RankedMax[x, 1]], tab] // TableForm
```

The last line will cause an error, and I do not understand why, because the documentation says:

> RankedMax[{Subscript[x, 1],...,Subscript[x, m]},1] is equivalent to
>   Max[{Subscript[x, 1],...,Subscript[x, m]}].

Why is this happening? Do I understand something incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect this has to do with the fact that `Max` has attribute `Flat`, and `RankedMax` hasn't. To get the same behaviour, you could do

```
(tab = Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 3}, {k, 1, 4}]) // TableForm
Map[Function[{x}, x/Max[x]], tab] // TableForm
Map[Function[{x}, x/RankedMax[Flatten[x], 1]], tab] // TableForm
```

As an aside, `//` binds stronger than `=` which means that is you do something like

```
a = b // TableForm
```

this is interpreted as `a = TableForm[b]` which is probably not what you want if you want to use `a` for further calculations. To prevent this you can use brackets to group the right terms together, i.e. `(a = b) // TableForm`.

Comment: I lost my internet connection while posting, thought it had posted. Now I see that it only posted it when my connection got back so I'm deleting it. It's too similar

Comment: @Rojo our answers are eerily similar.

Comment: Yeah, +1 for you on behalf of both

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure I'll even the score one day :-)

Comment: Thank you for making this a little bit more clear. I didn't know that // binds stronger, but I would have found out one day...

regarding the "feature": how can I know and expect this behaviour? How can I check the "attributes" of the functions? Is there anything else that can go wrong if the documentation says they are equivalent when in fact they are not?

Comment: @james This "feature" is called an attribute. You can check the attributes of a function with `Attributes[fun]`, set them with `SetAttributes[fun, attr]` and clear them with `ClearAttributes[fun, attr]`. You can read more about the available attributes and what they do in the documentation center.

Comment: OK. I have learnt something here. Shall we leave the "bug" flag on the case then?

Comment: @james The `bugs` tag is actually reserved for problems that have been confirmed as a bug (by community consensus or another authoritative source), not for suspected bugs. Maybe `functions` is a better tag in this case.